# How to set up Selenium Grid to run InternetExplorerDriver in C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-grid

I'm currently struggling to set up Selenium Grid to execute Selenium Webdriver Tests written in C#.

The WebDriver Tests are located on my my machine.

I installed the RC Standalone in my VM.

When using the following code

```
public static IWebDriver Instance { get; set; }
Instance = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://192.xxx.x.xxx:4444/wd/hub"), DesiredCapabilities.Firefox());
```

The tests run fine in the VM (firefox is launched and the tests are exceuted as expected)

The issue is when I am trying to use InternetExplorer

1) I changed the DesiredCapabilities to Internet Explorer in my test:

```
public static IWebDriver Instance { get; set; }

Instance = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("192.xxx.x.xxx:4444/wd/hub"), DesiredCapabilities.InternetExplorer());
```

2) Downloaded the InternetWebDriverServer.exe and Install it in the VM (not my local machine where the tests reside)
C:\Selenium\IEDriver (this C: is the VM one)

3 - Configured the RC Grid in the VM with the following command line:

```
java -jar C:\Selenium\RC\selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.j
ar -Dwebdriver.internetexplorer.driver=C:\Selenium\IEDriver\IEDriverServer.exe
```

When I run the tests, I get the following error

> The path to the to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.ie.driver system property.

N.B: The tests run perfectly fine on my local machine using

```
IEWebDriverServer.exe with the following code
public static IWebDriver Instance { get; set; }

Instance = new InternetExplorerDriver(@"C:\Libraries");
```

Answer (score 0):

The error states exactly what you are missing.

The error message says:

> The path to the to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.ie.driver system property

You are setting `webdriver.internetexplorer.driver`.  You need to set `webdriver.ie.driver`

(**ie** vs **internetexplorer**)

Comment: I changed the code to -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=C:\Selenium\IEDriver\IEDriverServer.exe
as you suggested. I am still getting the same error message.

Comment: I have also removed the -D to be exactly webdriver.ie.driver=
same message occured

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how I init my driver for IE11

```
public void Initialize()
        {
            String webURL = "http://www.google.com";
            String myHub = "http://QA_HUB:4444/wd/hub";
            var caps = DesiredCapabilities.InternetExplorer();
            caps.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, "internet explorer");
            caps.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Platform, "VISTA");
            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri(myHub), caps, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(600));
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(webURL);
            Console.WriteLine("Opened Browser & Navigated To URL");
        }
```

The IEDriverServer.exe is saved in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\bin and ensure that you have the folder pointed in System Settings Path and not the actual exe.